# How can we find the name of the employee having second highest salary in a Map(key -employee name, value-salary) using java 8 stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

We have a map Map<String, Long> which store employee name as string and employee salary as value. The task is to get the name with of the employee who has the second highest salary among the employees stores in this hashmap.

Comment: You can achieve that using stream api:
`String secondHighestSalaryEmployee = salaryMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed()).skip(1).findFirst().map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse("No employee found");`

Comment: Thanks Paul. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @PaulSerre don’t do the homework of other people. They should atleast try it so they have the chance to learn something.

Answer (score 1):

**Consider the following map as input**

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("anil",1000);
    map.put("ankit",1200);
    map.put("bhavna",1300);
    map.put("james",1400);
    map.put("micael",1500);
    map.put("tom",1600);
    map.put("daniel",1700);
```

**We want to fetch second highest salary with employee name. This can be achieved by below code.**

```
Map.Entry<String,Integer> finalResult = map.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(entry -> -entry.getValue())) //desc order
      .toList()
      .get(1); // index start from 0
```

Comment: Don’t do the homework of other user if they do not show any afford to solve it by themselves. They will not learn anything and  always ask here in the hope we do there work.

Comment: `.skip(1).findFirst().orElseThrow()` instead of `.toList().get(1)` will avoid the overhead of copying all the data to a new list that gets immediately thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by collecting into `TreeSet` with a comparator by the `Entry::getValue()`. Poll last twice to get the 2nd largest result.

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of(
        "Tom", 15,
        "Jerry", 17,
        "Silvester", 10,
        "Tweety", 12
);

NavigableSet<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> set = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
                () -> new TreeSet<>(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())));

Map.Entry<String,Integer> last = set.pollLast();                // Jerry=17
        Map.Entry<String,Integer> secondLast = set.pollLast();  // Tom=15
```

Comment: The OP Is asking for the *second* highest value. Can still be done in one pass, though.

Comment: @khachik I read the question wrong. Thanks for pointing it out. I came up with a solution to find the 2nd largest one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody has posted a simple `O(n)` solution:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a",10);
        map.put("b",12);
        map.put("c",20);
        map.put("d",18);
        map.put("e",14);
        map.put("f",16);
    
        Entry<String, Integer> highest = null;
        Entry<String, Integer> secondHighest = null;
        for(Entry<String, Integer> entry:map.entrySet()) {
            if(highest == null) {
                highest = entry;
            } else if(secondHighest == null) {
                secondHighest = entry;
            } else if(highest.getValue() <= entry.getValue()) {
                secondHighest = highest;
                highest = entry;
            } else if(secondHighest.getValue() <= entry.getValue()) {
                secondHighest = entry;
            } else {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Highest: " + highest.getKey() + ": " + highest.getValue());
        System.err.println("Second highest: " + secondHighest.getKey() + ": " + secondHighest.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a TreeMap, which is an implementation of Map, you can provide a comparator at the time of its creation to sort the data which is entered into it, automatically. In this way, you can directly fetch your desired result.